# System Variables used in Mysql 4.0.27

Tags: mysql

What are the system variables supported my Mysql server 4.0.27 ? I want to set the variable "sql-mode" thats available in all latest Mysql editions, in 4.0.27, as am using that version now. But am getting an error when my application is trying to connect with the DB. The error is "Failed to execute command 'SET SESSION' sql-mode."

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

> SET SESSION sql_mode='NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION';

or

> SET @@SESSION.sql_mode='NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION';